# trouble navigating with file based router on Dynamic route

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

The file based routing hasn't exactly clicked all the way for me.  The earlier NextJS  `pages` file routing worked easily.  I haven't made the conversion to Expo Route file based for some reason.  Possibly because of the combo of Stacks & Tabs & Slots.  I have been reading through the [dynamic route docs](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/create-pages/#dynamic-routes).
When I navigate to `/pattern/[id]` from within my tabs screen, something is getting lost in translation as Expo is not finding the route.  I have tried all sorts of things, but I think it's related to my folder structuring.
What I would like is: the destination `/pattern/[id]` to be a child of (tabs), not search.

```
app
  |__(auth)
     |__ _layout.tsx
     |__(tabs)
       |__ index.tsx
       |__ _layout.tsx
       |
       |__ search
       | |__ index.tsx // <-- from where I navigate from
       | |__ _layout.tsx
       |
       |__ pattern // <-- where I want to navigate to
       |  |__ _layout.tsx
       |  |__ [id].tsx // <-- dynamic pattern id name 
       |__ // other tabs content is ok since no navigation
```

Here is my Tab's _layout :

```
export default function TabLayout() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="search"
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="pattern"
        options={{
          href: null, // based on docs this will hide the tab
      />
  </Tabs>
 )
};
```

On my search UI, when I press on an item to navigate to,

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/pattern', // I have also tried pathname: '/pattern/[id]', 
  params: { 
    id: dynamicLabelId
  },
});
```

The error from Expo is that the route cannot be found. What happened to the `pattern` route?:
[image]

Here is my current sitemap from Expo:
[image: sitemap]

I have since added a different Pattern _layout instead of a Slot, using a Stack:

```
export default function PatternLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="[id]"
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

but this doesn't seem to resolve it...
I am asking for help on:

1. why is `router.push({ pathname: '/pattern', params: { id: label },});` not working right?
2. is my file structure ok?  Do I need a Stack Screen inside Pattern to capture the `[id].tsx` page?
   thank you in advance

Comment: check discord, i think i posted an answer there :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I would make two comments here:

1. If you want to hide a tab, don't use `href: null`, instead use `tabBarButton: () => null`, this will hide the tab without messing with the routing.
2. Your routing declaration `router.push({ pathname: '/pattern', params: { id: label },})` will send the router to the following url:  `/pattern?id:123`.  But what you actually want is it to go to `/pattern/123`.
   To do this, try using `` router.push({ pathname: /pattern/`${label}` `` .

This is working for me with dynamic routing, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. What about the file based routing folder setup, within (tabs) group?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one `router.push({pathname:'/(auth)/(tabs)/pattern/,  params: { id: dynamicLabelId })`